# AddCorrelationIdForwarding Not working from Hangfire Jobs

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, hangfire

I Have a HttpClient in a .NET 6 Application and I am using the method AddCorrelationIdForwarding()

```
     services.AddHttpClient<IMyHttpClient, MyHttpClient>(client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration["BaseUrl"]);
    }).AddCorrelationIdForwarding();
```

While calling from Controller, CorrelationId is correctly passing to the internal Api via IHttpClient. But If I called the same IMyHttpClient.Method() via Hangfire Job, it is not appending the CorrelationId Header in the request.

Comment: I did not know about `AddCorrelationIdForwarding` can you elaborate on this ?

Comment: Its forwarding or adding if not exist the guid header value and it is passed to all the httprequests